# When I run this Python code on my notebook it return empty table. I get this error How can I overcome this error?

Tags: python, dataframe, xpath, html-table, append

```
venues = results['response']['groups'][0]['items']
SGnearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON
# filter columns
filtered_columns = ['venue.name', 'venue.categories', 'venue.location.lat', 'venue.location.lng']
SGnearby_venues =SGnearby_venues.loc[:, filtered_columns]
# filter the category for each row
SGnearby_venues['venue.categories'] = SGnearby_venues.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)
# clean columns
SGnearby_venues.columns = [col.split(".")[-1] for col in SGnearby_venues.columns]

SGnearby_venues.shape
```

Here is the Error message and it does not explain much about what is wrong with the code and the type of error I get is KeyError

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a945df6402f0> in <module>
----> 1 venues = results['response']['groups'][0]['items']
      2 SGnearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON
      3 # filter columns
      4 filtered_columns = ['venue.name', 'venue.categories', 'venue.location.lat', 'venue.location.lng']
      5 SGnearby_venues =SGnearby_venues.loc[:, filtered_columns]

KeyError: 'groups'
```

May someone help me cross the Error?

Comment: please include (a snippet) the data that is in results

Comment: if you need to be able to run this code while you are not sure if results is empty (or in the structure you need) you should use try: and catch the keyerror

Comment: Can you post at least part of `results`?

Comment: Here is the part of the results.
results = requests.get(url).json()

Comment: That's not it; that's the variable declaration. Try to post at least part of the output of `print(results)`. While you are at it, also post the output of `print(type(results))`.

Comment: I got the solution and the problem was CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Key error usually means, that the key does not exist. So your `results['response']` has no key `'groups'`.

Comment: Thank you for now I know what the KeyError mean

Answer (score 0):

The KeyError: 'groups' I was getting was because of the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, because they where out dated the ones I was using there but after updating them from Foursquare everything started working fine